# Counter Not Working Correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code looks up a text file to see if there are any matches. For example, a line may be "charlie RY content" and the next line may be "charlie content". However, the counter seems to be off and isn't counting correctly.

```
file = open("C:/file.txt", "rt")
data = file.readlines()
dictionary = dict()
counter = 0
count = 0
setlimit = 10 #int(input("Please enter limit for N. Then press enter:"))
parameter = ["RY", "TZ"]
for j in data:
    user = j.split()[0]
    identify = j.split()[1]
    for l in identify:
        #l = a[1:2]
        if user not in dictionary.keys() and identify not in parameter:
            count = 1
            data = dictionary.update({user:count})
            break
            #print(user, count,"<-- Qualifies")
        elif user in dictionary.keys() and identify not in parameter:
            data = dictionary.update({user: count})
            count += 1
            break
print(dictionary)
```

As seen in the code, it looks for either RY or TZ and ignores this line and if a line without this condition is met, the counter will increase by one.

Sample Data:

```
charlie TZ this is a sentence
zac this is a sentence
steve RY this is a sentence
bob this is a sentence
bob this is another sentence
```

Expected Output:

```
{zac:1, bob:2}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data with current output and expected output?

Comment: @AChampion, please see updated question.

Comment: @AChampion, please see updated question.

Comment: BTW, there's no need to read the whole file into a list of lines and then iterate over the list. You can iterate directly over the file lines. And it's inefficient to call `.split()` twice on each line.

Comment: @PM2Ring, how would I change the file loading?

Comment: You can just do `for j in file:` to loop over the lines. And I just that you have `for l in identify:`. But `identify` is a string, so that loop iterates over the characters of that string.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do with `count`. Do you want to keep a separate count for each user that counts how many valid lines contain that user's name?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to augment the count,

```
count += 1
```

must come before

```
dictionary.update({user: count})
```

---

In other words,

```
elif user in dictionary.keys() and identify not in parameter:
    count += 1
    dictionary.update({user: count})
    break
```

---

Note that `dictionary.update(...)` modifies `dictionary` and returns `None`. 
Since it always returns `None`, there is no need to save the value in `data`.

---

Alternatively, as [pointed out by Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50435725/counter-not-working-correctly-in-python/50435813?noredirect=1#comment87885725_50435813), you could use

```
for j in data:
    ...
    if identify not in parameter:
        count += 1
        dictionary[user] = count
```

Note that you don't need to handle the assignment in two different cases.
The assignment `dictionary[user] = count` will create the new key/value pair if `user` is not in `dictionary`, and it will assign the new value, `count`, even if it is.

Note that the single `count` variable is getting increased by one whenever the conditional is True *for any user*. 
If you want the `dictionary[user]` to increase by one independently for each user, then use

```
for j in data:
    ...
    if identify not in parameter:
        dictionary[user] = dictionary.get(user, 0) + 1
```

`dictionary.get(user, 0)` returns `dictionary[user]` if `user` is in `dictionary`, otherwise it returns 0.

---

Another alternative is to use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import collections
dictionary = collections.defaultdict(int)
for j in data:
    ...
    if identify not in parameter:
        dictionary[user] += 1
```

With `dictionary = collections.defaultdict(int)`, 
`dictionary[user]` will be assigned the default value `int()` whenever `user` is not in `dictionary`. Since

```
In [56]: int()
Out[56]: 0
```

`dictionary[user]` is automatically assigned the default value of 0 when `user` is not in `dictionary`.

---

Also, `user in dictionary` is more idiomatic Python than `user in dictionary.keys()`, though they both return the same boolean value. In fact, you already use this idiom in 
when you say `identify not in parameter`.

While we're on the topic of idioms, it is generally better to use [a `with`-statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) to open files:

```
with open("data", "rt") as f:
```

since this will guarantee that the file handle `f` gets closed automatically for you when Python leaves the `with`-statement (either by reaching the end of the code inside the statement, or even if an exception is raised.)

---

Since `identify` is assigned string values such as `'TZ'`, the loop

```
for l in identify:
```

assigns values such as `T`, then `Z` to the variable `l`. 
`l` is not used inside the loop, and there is no apparent reason to be looping over the characters in `identify`. Therefore, you probably want to remove this loop.

---

Testing for membership in a set is on average [a O(1) (constant speed) operation](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), while testing for membership in a list is O(n) (the time generally increases with the size of the list.) So it is better to make `parameter` a set:

```
parameter = set(["RY", "TZ"])
```

---

Instead of calling `j.split` twice,

```
user = j.split()[0]
identify = j.split()[1]
```

you only need to call it once:

```
user, identify = j.split(maxsplit=2)[:2]
```

Note that both these assume that there is at least one whitespace in `j`.
If there isn't, the original code snippet will raise `IndexError: list index out of range`, while the second raises `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`.

`maxsplit=2` tells `split` to stop splitting the string after (at most) two splits are done. This could save some time if `j` is a large string with many split points.

---

So putting it all together,

```
import collections
dictionary = collections.defaultdict(int)
setlimit = 10 #int(input("Please enter limit for N. Then press enter:"))
parameter = set(["RY", "TZ"])
with open("C:/file.txt", "rt") as f:
    for line in f:
        user, identify = line.split(maxsplit=2)[:2]
        if identify not in parameter:
            dictionary[user] += 1

dictionary = dict(dictionary)
print(dictionary)
```

Comment: Doesn't using `count` actually give the wrong answer? e.g. 4 sentences starting like `'zac', 'zac', 'bob', 'bob'` would report `{'zac': 2, 'bob': 4}`.

Comment: @AChampion: Yes, I think you're right. I'll edit to address this.

Comment: Try to run your code on my example. With your code I get `{'bob': 6, 'zac': 5}`. That is, the counter does not reset for each user. While @Dave did not explain what he is counting, I would imagine this is not what OP would want.

Comment: You have to handle the case `user` is not in the `dictionary`: `dictionary[user] = dictionary.get(user, 0) + 1` would work (as would a `collections.defaultdict`)

Comment: @AChampion Thank you for pointing this out. It is now receiving the output result as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @unutbu said, you need to **NOT** reset `count` or **continue incrementing it** for *other users*!

```
        if user not in dictionary.keys() and identify not in parameter:
            dictionary[user] = 1
            break
            #print(user, count,"<-- Qualifies")
        elif user in dictionary.keys() and identify not in parameter:
            dictionary[user] += 1
            break
```

Without this change, @unutbu answer would still have incorrect counting logic from OP. For example, for this input:

```
charlie TZ this is a sentence
zac this is a sentence
steve RY this is a sentence
bob this is a sentence
bob this is another sentence
zac this is a sentence
zac this is a sentence
bob this is a sentence
```

your original logic would give the results:

```
{'bob': 4, 'zac': 3}
```

when both should be equal to 3.

---

`for l in identify:` probably is not needed and actually likely interferes with the results.

---

**TO SUMMARIZE:** Your code could look like this:

```
file = open("C:/file.txt", "rt")
dictionary = dict()
setlimit = 10 #int(input("Please enter limit for N. Then press enter:"))
parameter = ["RY", "TZ"]                                                
for j in file:                                                          
    user, identify = j.split()[:2]
    if identity in parameter:     
        continue                  
    if user in dictionary.keys():
        dictionary[user] += 1         
    else:                              
        dictionary[user] = 1      
file.close()       
print(dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have been given other answers that cover your current approach. But it should be noted that python already has a `collections.Counter` object that does the same thing.
Just to demonstrate using a `Counter` (note: this uses Py3 for `*` unpacking):

```
In []:
from collections import Counter
parameter = {"RY", "TZ"}
with open("C:/file.txt") as file:
    dictionary = Counter(u for u, i, *_ in map(str.split, file) if i not in parameter)

print(dictionary)

Out[]:
Counter({'bob': 2, 'zac': 1})
```

Comment: Might as well make `parameter` a set while you're at it. I suspect that gen exp will be a bit too advanced for the OP.

Comment: Good point, and I would imagine so - something that may spark some curiosity :)